# libgdx Gdx.graphics.getWidth is not returning the right value

Tags: android, firebase, libgdx

I have created an android game with Libgdx. It seemed to work good. After I have released it to the playstore, it won't use the higher resolution of my phone:

Update:
It seems that I am not the only one with this problem. I found the following thread that describes the same problem with Unity: [Link to unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/resolution-changes-on-android-device-after-build.821868/)

It seems to be a setting in the google play console, or some game optimisation on my device. Until now I have not found a good solution.
Is there anyone that recognises this problem and has a good explanation?

Changing the packagename solves the problem locally, but I fear it will come back after I release it in the google play store.

This is how I first described the problem:

Normally when the phone is in WQHD mode and no firebase is implemented getWidth en getHeight returns 2560 and 1440 as expected.
The same application with firebase support returns 1920x1080 in this mode.
After the phone is set to FHD mode both versions of my app returns 1920 x 1080 as expected.

I double checked this with a tablet, there the same behaviour is seen.

I also created a testprogram where I implemented firebase, this gives me the same result.

Why won't  my app see the full WHQD resolution when firebase is implemented.